# Create ListViewItem with a function

Tags: c#, listview, listviewitem

I tried to create a function that creates a `ListViewItem` and put it in my `ListView`, but when I use it the second time it just overwrites the first item.

This is the function:

```
ListViewItem lvi = new ListViewItem(taskName2);
lvi.SubItems.Add(DateTime2);
lvi.SubItems.Add(More2);
listView1.Items.Add(lvi);
```

How can I do it without overwriting the first item? Is there is a array of `ListViewItem` or something?

Comment: Can you show how this is being used?

Comment: its simple call
` public Form1(string taskName1,string DateTime1,string More1,bool startworkign)
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            taskName2 = taskName1;
            DateTime2 = DateTime1;
            More2 = More1;
            if(startworkign)
            {
                StartWorking();
            }
        }`
its called every time the form started

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a new, separate object for each item in the list, you are adding a pointer to the same object. For example, if you put that whole block in a for loop it should work.

```
List<ListViewItem> listViewItemHandles = new List<ListViewItem>();
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    ListViewItem lvi = new ListViewItem(taskName2);
    lvi.SubItems.Add(DateTime2);
    lvi.SubItems.Add(More2);
    listView1.Items.Add(lvi);

    listViewItemHandles.Add(lvi);
}
```

Comment: yes I know I have a counter for my items but I don't know how to add a pointer to the item name to create a separate object.
something like:

ListViewItem lvi + counter = new ListViewItem(taskName2)

I know I should do that but how? how I can add my count to the name of the item?.

Comment: I don't fully understand  why you need a count. If you want handles to the items, store the objects you create in an array.

Comment: I made an example with a `List<T>` since it is more flexible and probably better for your purposes.

Comment: you don't understand me sorry.I meant that every time the function works the function create a new item and put it in the listview but in the second time the function works he overwrite the item that created and made in the first time. I don't want to create multiple items in one function work. I just want to create a new item every time the function works

Comment: Then put the code block in a function, it should work.

Comment: No, its again overwrite on the first item that he create.

Comment: Sorry I am out of ideas.